# Will Workflow Manager 1.0 be supported by Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager, discussion

Will  Workflow Manager 1.0 be supported by Windows Server 2012 R2? If it doesn't support please let me know the process to install the Workflow Manager in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 3):

**In short,** Yes, it is supported.

For more details check,

- [How to install and configure Workflow Manager on Windows 2012 R2](https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-install-and-configure-Workflow-Manager-on-Windows-2012-R2.aspx)
- [Workflow Manager Supportability with SharePoint Server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dawiese/2017/11/15/workflow-manager-supportability-with-sharepoint-server/)